# taglist and local variable

Tags: vim, taglist

When using `taglist` plugin in VIM we can use `Ctrl` + `]` to jump to a global variable or a function. However if the variable is local, then it cannot find in the tags. I found from this [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Go_to_definition_using_g) that we can jump to the local variables by using `gd` or global variable using `gD`.

Since this is out of scope of the taglist command, we cannot use `Ctrl` + `t` to return back to the place where we jumped from.

Is it possible to enhance `taglist` to jump to a local variable in case if no tag is found? And then use the stack to return back to the place where it jumped from?

Comment: Surely you could implement that as a patch (so the answer to your question is "YES"), however, this isn't core tag functionality, so the plugin's author may not accept it for inclusion.

Comment: @IngoKarkat can you give me a hint how can I develop this patch? I will need to over-ride the behavior of  `Ctrl` + `]` key

Comment: First, `<C-]>` is not related *in any way* to the Taglist plugin. Second, `<C-]>` jumps to the first matching tag, no matter what file it's in. If you want the ability to choose what file you jump to, try `g]`.

Comment: Assuming that by "local variables" you mean `s:` variables in Vim scripts, your problem is the interaction between `crags` and the default `iskeyword`. Add this to a file `after/syntax/vim.vim` to fix it: `setlocal iskeyword+=:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mapping. Because the Taglist plugin actually doesn't define such (it only provides a display of tags of the current buffer, and sets up tags), no integration with it is required.

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-]> :<C-u>let pos = [bufnr('')] + getpos('.')<Bar>execute 'normal!' (v:count ? v:count : '') . "\<lt>C-]>"<CR>:if pos == [bufnr('')] + getpos('.')<Bar>execute 'normal! gd'<Bar>endif<CR>
```

This first records the current buffer and cursor position, then tries to perform the normal tag jump. If the position hasn't changed, we fall back to the `gd` command. Oh, actually we don't need to check the position, and can use `try...catch` instead. Version 2:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-]> :<C-u>try<Bar>execute 'normal!' (v:count ? v:count : '') . "\<lt>C-]>"<Bar>catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E426:/<Bar>execute 'normal! gd'<Bar>endtry<CR>
```

Comment: not exactly what I wanted, but pretty close. thanks for the solution.